# Disabled Users in SharePoint 2013 - Best practices

Tags: 2013, active-directory, filter, user-profile-service

What is the best practice for managing disabled users? Should these be imported in SharePoint? And if not, how to filter these records?

SharePoint 2013, Synchronization option in User Profile Service

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the users have already disabled from Active directory and you need to exclude them in SharePoint , you should do the following

- Centeral Administration > Application Management > Mange Service Application > Manage User Profile Service .
- Below Suncronization > Configure Syncronization Connection.

[image]

- Edit Connection Filters.

[image]

- At Exclusion Filter for Users > set `UserAccountControl Bit on Equals 2`

[image]

- Now Start Full Profile Synchronization .

Answer (score 2):

you can filter the Disbaled user from User Profile Sync using the Connection filter as M.Qassas Mentioned in his post.

> The User Profile Synchronization timer job marks for deletion users
>   who have been deleted from the directory source. When the My Site
>   cleanup job runs, it looks for all users marked for deletion and
>   deletes their profiles. Respective My Sites are then assigned to the
>   manager for the deleted user and an e-mail message notifies the
>   manager of this deletion. All this is handled when you have MySite
>   Cleanup timer Job enabled.

In Most cases companies loses the mysite of disabled user due to this. In that case(if you have mysites in your company), Disabled MySite Cleanup timer Job and manually delete the User from the Profile Store, along with set the connection filter.

[Check this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff681014%28v=office.15%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#RemoveObsUsers)

Comment: Thanks M.Qassas and Waqas! Setting "UserAccountControl Bit on Equals 2" does not work for me. Maу be because the UserAccountControl property has different values like 512, 544 or 66080. The second thing is that the OU of disabled users is not selected in sync properties, but these users are still in SP, even after full timer job.

Comment: And also thanks for the link. But I run `Set-SPProfileServiceApplication $upa -GetNonImportedObjects $true` command it hangs for a long time with no response.

Comment: So it seems to me that the only way is to manually using PowerShell remove disabled users from the profile store and then somehow try to correctly configure UPSA sync properties. Am I right?

Comment: If the value is not 2 then user is not disabled in AD.check this in for values translation https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/305144 now to stop the disabled user importing into user profile,we need to setup connection filters as mentioned after that run full profile sync followed couple of incremental sync. Script is only for deleting exiting disabled user in profile store.

Comment: After setting the UserAccountControl filter, then full synchronization and MySite Cleanup timer Job disabled users are still in store. So the only way for cleaning disabled users is to write powershell script. Right?

Comment: After that if you go for user profiler page in central admin> manager user profile...over here if you search for the disable user what it returns...is it Mark for deletion or not ?

Comment: could you please suggest how to set a filter on account OU's in User Profile Exclusions of AD DS connection?