# Remove Inactive Admins from SharePoint site collection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, active-directory, administration

Can anybody tell me how to identify and remove inactive administrators in a SharePoint site collection using power shell ?

Comment: what do u mean with inactive?

Comment: Users which left the company .They are not present in active directory but they are present in SharePoint .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case, you have configured `User Profile Sync service` you can **exclude** the deleted/disabled users to be synced in Sharepoint, I mentioned the detail steps in another thread at [Disabled Users in SharePoint 2013 - Best practices](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/192765/disabled-users-in-sharepoint-2013-best-practices)

**Otherwise**, SharePoint doesn't tell you which users are active or inactive, it's your manual job, you should **specify** which user you need to delete from SharePoint.

---

**To delete user from Site Collection using Powershell**

```
#Get the Root web
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://sharepoint.stackechange"
#Specify the user account
$UserAccount = "Stackexchange\mqassas"
#Removes user from site collection
Remove-SPUser -Identity $UserAccount -Web $Web -Confirm:$False
```

Read more: [Delete Users from SharePoint Site Collection using PowerShell](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/07/delete-users-from-site-collection-using-powershell.html)

---

**An alternative way to delete Accounts from the Site Collection.**

- Navigate to `http://MQassas/_layouts/15/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=0`
- Select your users > Action > Delete Users from Site Collection.