# Remove-PnPSiteCollectionAdmin on none existing users

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

We are trying to clean up site collection administrators with following command:

```
Remove-PnPSiteCollectionAdmin
```

The problem is if the user has been removed from AD then this command fails. How do we clean up that kind of users?

Thanks in advance, Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code can be used,

```
#Get the Root web
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://sharepoint.stackechange"
#Specify the user account
$UserAccount = "Stackexchange\mqassas"
#Removes user from site collection
Remove-SPUser -Identity $UserAccount -Web $Web -Confirm:$False
```

Ref link-  [Remove Inactive Admins from SharePoint site collection](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218512/remove-inactive-admins-from-sharepoint-site-collection)

Comment: I will test asap. Thanks for fast response.

Comment: Did this work ?

Comment: It did. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

What did you mean that the command fails? Was there an error displaying?

In my testing, I could remove a deleted user from site collection administrators using the PNP cmdlet.

Before you remove the deleted user from the site collection administrators, you need to make sure there are other site collection administrators(at least one) for the site collection except the deleted user.

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/anthony -Credentials (Get-Credential)

Remove-PnPSiteCollectionAdmin -Owners "anthony@xxx.onmicrosoft.com"
```

Comment: It fails when the user you try to delete is not in the AD anymore. Let me reproduce it so I can get error info. Do your call works on deleted users too?

Comment: yes, i deleted the users 10 days ago, and the user is a site collection of a site, I could remove the users from the site collection using the cmdlet. I updated me answer and provided the entire code i used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below command to get all the users currently privileged as "Site Collection Administrators" and remove them .

Get-PnPSiteCollectionAdmin | Remove-PnPSiteCollectionAdmin